# Error while connecting to port 1883

Tags: mqtt

I have a Rpi-A connected to internet via 3G surf-stick and Rpi-B connected to internet via a WiFi hotspot. Rpi-A has a public ip address and also ports 1883 and 8883 are open. Both raspberry Pi's are on different networks. I am attempting to send binary data using MQTT from Rpi-B to Rpi-A.

update: I used the below code to test the MQTT connection. replacing XX.XX.XX.XX with public IP of raspberry Pi. Still I end up getting this error--->

> error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

what might be the possible reason for this error ? Is there anything missing in my code

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect

client.connect("xx.xx.xxx.x", 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()

while True:
  time.sleep(2)
  client.publish('Due_0.72/cmd/in','hello')
  print "publish.."
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that Rpi-A has a publicly routable IP address? Most Cellular providers use large scale NAT and you need a specific plan to get a routable address. If so have you checked to see if iptables is blocking inbound traffic?

Comment: I just put the IP address in online port check utility and found that ports are open. But how do I check if iptables is blocking inbound traffic?

Comment: @hardilib I run this command on rpi-A  : sudo iptables -L -nv and there is no inbound firewall blocking

Comment: You've double checked that the broker is actually running on rpi-a? Other than that without having hands on to play, hard to say

Comment: @hardilib yes MQTT broker is running on both raspberry pi's